# Access Intern environment in test to get browser name

Tags: intern

I want to take screenshots of every scenario in  my tests, and on every browser.

Currently I have failing tests on firefox but not chrome and so I'd like a nice way to see the failure quickly, so i'm trying to prefix the browser name to the screenshot file name.

I can access the capabilities object through `this.remote.session.capabilities` and get the `browserName` property from it. I'm using this like so:

```
    bdd.before(function(){
        this.remote.setFindTimeout(5000);
        browser = this.remote.session.capabilities.browserName;
    });
```

coupled with

```
function saveScreenshot(name, screenshot) {
    var dir = './screenshots';
    if (!fs.existsSync(dir)){
        fs.mkdirSync(dir);
    }
    fs.writeFileSync(dir + '/' + browser + '_' + name, screenshot)
};
```

However, when running on chrome and firefox, I only get screenshots named `firefox_screenshotname.png` - no chrome!

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question - turns out I had defined my 'browser' variable in the wrong place. As per https://theintern.github.io/intern/#interface-object, any variable that will be modified (or used in my case) by the tests should be declared in the test suite function.

```
define(function (require) {
    var bdd = require('intern!bdd');
    var expect = require('intern/chai!expect');
    var wiremock = require('./wiremock');
    var fs = require('intern/dojo/node!fs');

    // var browser <- doesn't work here!

    bdd.describe('some thing', function () {

        var browser; // Works here!

        bdd.before(function(){
            this.remote.setFindTimeout(5000);
            browser = this.remote.session.capabilities.browserName;
        });

        bdd.it('should search for a postcode', function () {
            return this.remote
                .get(require.toUrl('index.html'))
                .findAllByCssSelector('.thing')
                .getVisibleText()
                .then(function (text) {
                    expect(text).to.contain('Some stuff');
                })
                .takeScreenshot()
                .then(function (screenshot) {
                  saveScreenshot("thing.png", screenshot);
                });
        });

        function saveScreenshot(name, screenshot) {
            var dir = './screenshots';
            if (!fs.existsSync(dir)){
              fs.mkdirSync(dir);
            }
            fs.writeFileSync(dir + '/' + browser + '_' + name, screenshot)
        };
    });
});
```